# How do I display the values in a mySQL table in my website without using PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

Can't use PHP due to assignment restrictions. Just javascript, html and mySQL.

I've been trying to add a portfolio gallery to my website, with values from my 'food' table in mySQL being used in it. Portfolio entries would turn grey and show additional information when hovered over. Clicking on the navbar buttons would make only relevant portfolio entries show. The portfolio gallery would ideally look like this. (Hardcoded)

[image]
[image]
This is how my attempt went, with only my navbar showing and not my portfolio entries.

[Attempted Portfolio Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaTXn.png)

My SQL code behind the scenes for GET work properly, tested with Restlet Client, so I think the problem most likely has to do with the html code making use of those SQL codes. Can't figure out why though. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but any help would be appreciated!

Portfolio Entry HTML code (Hardcoded)

```
<div class="portfolio-item alacarte col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
          <div class="recent-work-wrap">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/recent-new/hamncheese.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="recent-work-inner">
                <h3>
                  <a href="#">Ham and Cheese Sandwich</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Ham, Cheese, Brioche Bread
                  <br>$1</p>
                <a class="preview" href="images/portfolio/full-new/hamncheese.png" rel="prettyPhoto">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

SQL Attempt as a script in the < head>  :

```
<script>
    function displayFoods() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // The route pattern '/movies' is registered in the routeMovies.js file.
        request.open("GET", "/food", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.onload = function() {
            // We create a 'movies' variable to store data of all movies retrieved  
            // from the server.
            // All movies will be stored in the form of an array in the movies variable.
            var foods = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            var totalFoods = foods.length;
            // Get the HTML element of the div where id="movieListings" so that
            // we can add HTML codes to display all the movies.
            var listings = document.getElementById("foodListings");

            // We use a for loop to traverse through the array of movies.
            // For every movie, we get the name and picture. 
            for (var count = 0; count < totalFoods; count++) {
                var name = foods[count].name;
                var picture = foods[count].picture;
                var foodType = foods[count].foodType;
                var info = foods[count].info;
                var price = foods[count].price;

                // We create the HTML codes for displaying each movie and store in a variable 'movieItem'.
                // We also insert each movie name and picture in the HTML codes. 
                var foodItem = '<div class="portfolio-item '+ foodType +' col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> \
                    <div class="recent-work-wrap"> \
                      <img class="img-responsive" src=" '+ picture +' " alt=""> \
                      <div class="overlay"> \
                        <div class="recent-work-inner"> \
                          <h3> \
                            <a href="#"> '+ name +' </a> \
                          </h3> \
                          <p> ' + info + ' \
                            <br>$1</p> \
                          <a class="preview" href=" ' + picture + ' " rel="prettyPhoto"> \
                            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a> \
                        </div> \
                      </div>\
                    </div>\
                  </div>';

                // We use the built-in JavaScript function insertAdjacentHTML() which is from 
                // the HTML element object to insert the HTML codes.                  
                listings.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', foodItem);
            }
        };

        // Send the request to get info of all movies.
        request.send();
    }
</script>
```

and in the actual html after the navbar code...

```
<div class="row" onload="displayFood()">
    <div class="portfolio-items" id="foodItem"></div>
</div>
```

I think that's about it for any relevant code. Again, thanks for any help!

Comment: There are extra spaces in the img.src and a.href fields. Do console.log the value of `totalFoods` to check that you get all the data.

Comment: @Adder seems like displayFoods() doesn’t get called, because nothing is being logged. I’ve also corrected the missing s in my onload displayFood() while I was at it.

Comment: Maybe try calling `displayFoods()` from body.onload.

Comment: @Adder Alright, my console.log came in the form of an Uncaught ReferenceError saying that totalFoods was not defined. There was also “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘insertAdjacentHTML’ of null at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload”

Comment: Did you place `console.log(totalFoods);` directly after `var totalFoods = foods.length;`? Do you have an element with id `foodListings` in your HTML page?

Comment: @Adder Nope and nope. Changed that since, and now totalFoods is being logged as 2 (yup, two rows in my food table) and now an error saying "GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Not Found)" is showing up.

Comment: I have no idea where this comes from, since the XMLHttpRequest works. Maybe something is wrong with `var picture = foods[count].picture;`

Comment: Just an aside: so the URL at "/food" is implemented using Restlet? So just Java instead of PHP I guess. You still need a server-side language of some kind, a restriction on using PHP for that seems a little arbitrary, but ok. You sure it didn't just mean to use client-side code (as opposed to server-side code) to do the production of the HTML and just have the server return data instead of markup? You've followed that pattern so I guess it's fine but clearly you need _something_ on the server in order to call mySQL, so saying it's HTML, JS, MySQL **only** makes no sense.

Comment: @Adder Alright, now the 404 error is gone. My portfolio entries still aren't showing up, though. All the console shows now is the log for totalFoods.

Comment: Did you fix the extra spaces in the img.src and a.href fields?

Comment: @ADyson Not using Restlet, per se. I just tested GET, POST, PUT and DELETE sql statements using Restlet Client. I've used XAMPP too to host the MySQL server, forgot to mention.

Comment: ah so you used Restlet as a client, not a server? The whole package supports both, I believe. And if you have XAMPP you I would assume you _are_ using PHP to respond to HTTP requests? Otherwise you cannot access your mySQL data dynamically. You may think I'm being pedantic but saying you're not going to use PHP (or A.N. Other server-side script) is nonsensical.

Comment: @Adder Yeah, removed the extra spaces.

Comment: @ADyson Just a student here, so I'll admit I don't know exactly what's going on there for XAMPP. You're most likely right. I usually turn on just the MySQL server when testing or whatnot, but I sometimes turn on the Apache server for phpMyAdmin so I could easily insert rows into my tables.

Comment: didn't you write the code for the "/food" URL you're calling?? You can't access MySQL directly from Javascript. There is (or should be) some code at that URL which is querying the database and returning the results. The code you've labelled as "SQL attempt" is actually some Javascript which makes a HTTP request to the URL via AJAX and receives the response in JSON format. Nothing directly to do with a database. Are you getting your terminology confused?

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I did think "SQL attempt" was a bit of a sketchy caption to put, but I didn't know anything else that was appropriate. I'm new to this, after all.

Comment: No worries, I just pointed out because it's good to try and get your head round all the different components of your system and what they do